# enable 443 port for TURN server

Tags: amazon-web-services, turn

What is that one port i need to open in ec2 instance so that it will allow me to open below link on ssl as well.

[Without HTTPS](http://live.talkrecruit.com:3478)   --this is working fine

[With Https](https://live.talkrecruit.com:3478)   --this is giving error

please help

Answer (score 0):

You Will need Port `443` Open in Security Group for HTTPS to work , also make sure if it is windows Instance Windows Firewall has that port Open.

Comment: hie, its a linux ec2 instance on AWS
https://live.talkrecruit.com is working but when i append port to it HTTPS is not working, dont know what to add as a inbound/outboud rules to make it work

Comment: I mentioned in answer 443

Answer (score 0):

Your working link is specifying port `3478`: http://live.talkrecruit.com:3478/

Your non-working version is specifying HTTPS, but is also still specifying port `3478`: https://live.talkrecruit.com:3478/

Since you have configured HTTPS to be served on port `443`, you obviously need to change the port in the link to be `443`, like so: https://live.talkrecruit.com:443/

And since `443` is the default port for HTTPS, you can leave it off and the browser will automatically try to use port `443` like so: https://live.talkrecruit.com/

Comment: hi but i need to use port 3478 port on ssl, have seen many server like this
http://turn.quickblox.com:3478/
https://turn.quickblox.com:3478/

Comment: in short i want port 3478 to work on both http and https
my screenshot of inbound rules prnt.sc/h597yr

Comment: I honestly have no idea how those two links you just gave are working. That is a non-typical setup and there must be some sort of proxy sever in front of that domain that is somehow managing both protocols on the same port. A typical web server cannot support both HTTP and HTTPS on the same port. If the Turn server supports multiple protocols on the same port then I guess all you would need to do is configure it to use `3478` for the HTTPS port. Right now you have it configured to use `443` for HTTPS.